# Could there be infinite solutions to a modular linear equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Could there be infinite solutions to a modular linear equation of the form

Ax = b mod n

when solving for x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any solution and then add some multiple of $n$ to the $x$ which depending on your definition may or may not be different. For example, $x\equiv0\mod1$ would be all the integers in the same equivalence class for one view or a countably infinite set as $1,2,3,\cdots$ could each be thought of as 'different' in a sense.